# Including specific div class into my site

Tags: html

Please be aware my experience with coding is pretty much just CSS/HTML. I was also recently introduced to jQuery. But I am very willing to try out your solutions (if my skills permit).

So what I want to do is include the **reviews** from this site here:
[Airbnb - Mailodging](https://www.airbnb.ca/users/show/9187). Using Firefox's Inspect tool, I found that you can locate the div for just the reviews with this class:

> div.panel.reviews.space2

I've tried searching for a way to include a specific class (*not an ID#*) from an external page using iframes, but seems it's impossible. Is there a workaround or any other solution you can suggest?

At the moment the only way I found to include the reviews is through a hideous iframe. It displays the entire page, which I don't want. [You can see it here](http://m-lodging.atwebpages.com/reviews.php). Yuck! Seems I'm better off just opening the Airbnb page through a new tab.

Comment: You can use `jQuery.load()` to pull in a specific section of a remote webpage and put it anywhere on your webpage. If the section you need doesn't have an ID, you'll have to crawl the page with a scripting language like PHP to grab the content you need.

Comment: @NicholasPickering The `load()` call would violate the [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: There's an [unofficial Airbnb API](https://www.mashape.com/john-matt/airbnb) in the making. But it's not working yet.

Comment: Your best bet is to redirect users to your airbnb profile at the moment.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just decided to quote some of the reviews off of Airbnb and link to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) or [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to load your external html page into your current page. And within the callback function for each method, you can set, reference or modify your css selector that's on your external page, any way you want. You just gotta read up on the API on how to use it properly.  Good Luck!

Comment: This would violate the [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: ohh, the external content is not on the same domain?  then call it into your current page using an iframe.  but can you edit the external data yourself?  or not?  That is the big question.

Comment: Airbnb is a large commercial site from which the OP is looking to scrape their personal profile page - so no :)

Comment: ok, the only thing I can suggest is using jquery's contents() approach - read this up and give it a shot! -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924936/change-html-of-an-iframe-with-jquery  but that may not work unless that external page is also on your same domain.  but it doesn't hurt to try.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Nicholas, reviewing your site, and the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation the code could go something a little like this:

```
$('body.en').load('https://www.airbnb.ca/users/show/9187 div.reviews_section as_host');
```

Untested, so not sure if that will work 100% given that it's a remote site your retrieving from and not sure if this function was designed for that purpose, but give it a try.

Comment: actually, this violates the same-origin-policy. I disagree with my own comment.

Comment: Yes, something that I to had forgotten about. :(