# how can i see the document.getElementById value in another file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML file,with a label. Somewhere inside the page in a DIV i have an iframe,which it calls a HTML file. This HTML files calls a Javascript. I want to be able to change the innerHTML of the label in my JS file. Is there any way?

Comment: i think this will solve the problem

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5924949/2654814

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe

Comment: Are the parent and iframe pages all in the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you can use this js to change html in parent page from the iframe:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('label')
```

Comment: yeah! thats it. you save me!