# Inject or Find and Replace in an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

Is there any possibilities to inject a JavaScript or to find and replace a text in side the iframe?

For example:
www.xyz.com is my website and www.91sms.in is the remote site for which i don't have the access.

so my file looks like this (www.xyz.com/localiframe.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Cartin - Themes</title> 

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").children().each(function() {           
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/2016/g,"2014-16 Powered by 91sms.in"));
});
})
</script>

</head>
<body>

 <iframe width="100%" height="600px" src="http://www.91sms.in"> </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

In my iframe i want the script to search for 2016 in the iframe and it should be replaced by 2016-2017

i tried so many scripts but none of them are working, please give me some suggestion on this. please note that i dont have access to 91sms.in website.

Thank You

Comment: Nope, you don't have access to cross-origin iframes, for obvious reasons.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924936/change-html-of-an-iframe-with-jquery